# AndroidThings BluetoothAdapter not always enabling

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things

First let me say that AndroidThings is AMAZING! I like everything about the concept of getting Android into IOT. I am trying to bring AndroidThings to my company for use in production lines. Onto the question!

I have been trying to use Bluetooth low energy for communication with devices. I have gotten the Bluetooth working sometimes. That is I enable the Bluetooth adapter and it very quickly starts and I get scan results thereafter. Now say I do this another time, I check the adapter enable state, I try to enable and it just sits there. One way that seemed to work was to call BluetoothAdapter.disable() no matter what (maybe clearing something?) then performing a BluetoothAdapter.enable().

It seems like when using AndroidThings enabling the bluetooth hardware on the Pi is very 'finicky'. Also I have noticed that it may take up to 1 minutes to enable the Bluetooth.

Things to know:

- I have tested this on multiple PIs.
- I am using DP7 (though i saw this on DP6 also)
- The main problem I am seeing is the enabling of the
  bluetooth hardware (BluetoothAdapter)
- Yes I have all of the required permissions:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  ```
- Yes I have power cycled the PI after I have put the app
  on it.
- I have implemented a retry mechanism for enabling the adapter and it still sometimes does not work.
- I have followed the bluetooth tutorial on the AndroidThings page and I still get inconsistent results.

Has anyone else seen this issue or related issues?

Comment: If you are seeing intermittent behavior, please capture a log when the issue occurs and file a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=847005

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is solved in the new updated version of Android Things (1.0.1,updated June 2018)

> ### Resolved Issues:
>
> Raspberry Pi 3 devices with UART hardware connected fail to boot up.
>
> Bluetooth is disabled on the Raspberry Pi 3 due to an invalid hardware configuration. This hardware configuration is created by the starter kit settings in the Android Things Console.